# Alfred workflow to output to a text field

Tags: workflow, alfred

I'm writing a pretty simple workflow which is to read something from a file, and then output it to a text field, for example a web page input box.  For example the file is

```
a=b
```

I can search `a` and output `b` to the input box.  Which output should I choose here?  I only see it can be copied to clipboard...